# How to process the warning:cast to int* from smaller integer type int

Tags: c++, pointers, vtable

I have a base class as following:

`class Base{
public:
    virtual void f() { cout << "Base::f" << endl; }
};`

```
void testVTable(){
    typedef void (*Func)(void);
    Base b;
    Func pFunc = NULL;
    cout<<"vtable address:"<<(int*)(&b)<<endl;
    cout<<"virtual function address:"<<(int*)*(int*)(&b)<<endl;
    pFunc = (Func)(int*)*(int*)((&b)+0);
    pFunc();}
```

And I want to execute the function `f()` by using `f`'s address in virtual table.However, in MacOS the program crashed while it runned ok in windows 7. I know `int *` is 8 bytes and `int` is 4 bytes, and I tried using `size_t` to replace `int`, it didn't work.
I've no way to get it to work. Can someone help me?

Comment: And why (the hell) would you want to do this? This is undefined behaviour ten times over...

Comment: I just want to test vtable and know more about virtual functions!

Comment: Well you'll have to learn about different compiler ABIs. I guess you used MSVC on Windows, but Mac OS typically uses Clang. They have no reason to implement virtual dispatching identically, and as a matter of fact they don't -- hence, crash.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you manage to find correct function pointer offset in vtable (which is another quest) the function pointer stored there is definitely not a regular function pointer. Moreover it might be not a non-static member function pointer either so it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void testVTable(){
    typedef void (*Func)(void*);
    Base b;
    size_t vtblAddress = *(size_t*)&b;
    Func pFunc = (Func)(*(size_t*)(vtblAddress));
    pFunc(&b);
}
```

Comment: thanks. your answer looks better than mine, more clear to understand!

Answer (score -1):

I finally found something wrong with my code by debug using vs2015, below is the code that can properly run on vc6, vs2015 and Xcode.

```
void testVTable(){
    typedef void (*Func)(void);
    Base b;
    Func pFunc = NULL;
    cout<<"vtable address:"<<(size_t*)(&b)<<endl;
    cout<<"virtual function address:"<<(size_t*)*(size_t*)*(size_t*)(&b)<<endl;
    pFunc = (Func)(size_t*)*(size_t*)*(size_t*)((&b)+0);
    pFunc();}
```